# Why is a script in /etc/rc6.d not run on reboot?

Tags: linux, shutdown, init.d

I am trying to log shutdown/reboot on a Raspberry Pi. I am running latest Raspbian. This is my setup:

`cat /etc/init.d/log-shutdown.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          log-shutdown
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:     umountroot
# Should-Stop:
# Default-Start:
# Default-Stop:      0 6
# Short-Description: Log shutdown date.
### END INIT INFO

echo "I ran">/log-shutdown
```

`ls -Al /etc/init.d/log-shutdown.sh`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 258 Apr 15 20:10 /etc/init.d/log-shutdown.sh
```

`ls -Al /etc/rc0.d/*log-shutdown*`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Apr 15 19:41 /etc/rc0.d/K01log-shutdown.sh -> ../init.d/log-shutdown.sh
```

`ls -Al /etc/rc6.d/*log-shutdown*`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Apr 15 19:41 /etc/rc6.d/K01log-shutdown.sh -> ../init.d/log-shutdown.sh
```

After running `sudo shutdown -r now` and waiting for the Pi to reboot, `/log-shutdown` is not written to. Manually running `sudo /etc/init.d/log-shutdown.sh` does write to the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When the pi is running, what run level is it in (`sudo runlevel` might tell you).

Comment: `sudo runlevel` outputs `N 3`. It is a headless server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So. I appear to have found a solution, but I haven't a clue why it's needed, as it isn't on Ubuntu. `/etc/init.d/log-shutdown` (I removed the `.sh`) now looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          log-shutdown
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Log shutdown date
### END INIT INFO

case "$1" in
  start)
    touch /var/lock/subsys/log-shutdown
    ;;
  stop)
    date +%s > /data/log/log-shutdown
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/log-shutdown stop"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

The important bit is `touch /var/lock/subsys/log-shutdown`, which tells the init system that `log-shutdown` is running, so it bothers to run the stop script on shutdown/reboot. I think.

Comment: Yes, you've got it. You were probably expecting the old SysVInit behavior, where scripts are just run blindly at runlevel transitions. But now with Upstart and systemd in the way, the rules have changed. Basically, the new logic is trying to prevent a redundant `service foo stop` call during shutdown if the "service" was already stopped prior to shutdown.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It's curious that it isn't needed on Ubuntu 14.04, though, as that used Upstart I thought?

Comment: Not working on Ubuntu 18.04