# How to run a script at shutdown on Debian 9 or Raspbian 8 (Jessie)

Tags: shutdown, sysvinit, system-v

I would like to execute this shell script at reboot and shut down:

```
#!/bin/sh
touch /test
```

Its permissions are

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 22 Feb 24 09:34 /etc/init.d/te1
```

And it has this links

```
/etc/rc0.d/K01te1 -> ../init.d/te1
/etc/rc6.d/K01te1 -> ../init.d/te1
```

It is working at start up if I have a this link

```
/etc/rc5.d/S01te1 -> ../init.d/te1
```

But I need it running at shut down.

How can I do this on Debian 8 and 9 testing?

The [suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276808/159562) `touch /var/lock/subsys/te1` didn't work.

Comment: Why don't you use cron and `@reboot` ?

Comment: Because I need to copy something when the system shuts down. @reboot runs at startup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the impression that others seem to have problems in getting this running, too. Seems like starting with Debian 8.0 (Jessie) systemd breaks compatibility to System V init.

So [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/347333/159562) it was suggested to create a systemd service instead. The solution is [used here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/62536/58211) and looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=The te1 script

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/te1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The systemd service needs to be saved in `/lib/systemd/system/te1.service` and installed with `sudo systemctl enable te1`.

Comment: On Raspbian, this did not work until I ran `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`. I am not sure at what time the `daemon-reload` has to be run, whether it is after installing the service config, or after enabling the service a first time, or whether the service has to be enabled after daemon-reload, but I did get it working.

Answer (score 0):

seems you could find it with a bit of search but:
put your script at /etc/rc6.d
grant necessary permissions:

```
sudo chmod +x K99_script
```

**and some points**:
no .sh extension
 
K_99 is needed
scripts here are executed in alphabetical order
Read [here](http://ccm.net/faq/3348-execute-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. The article also seems to confuse rc0.d with rc6.d. Reboot is rc6.d!

Comment: it's not reboot it's shut down .

Comment: Look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel

Comment: This doesn't work on Jessie.

Answer (score -1):

Try to execute your script as a startscript in runlevel 6

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/te1 etc/rc0.d/S01te1
```

Comment: Thanks, I also tried this before without success. The reason is probably that K10reboot is executed first.

Comment: I have succesful tested it with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: The questioner explicitly said Debian 8 and 9, which are very different in this respect to Ubuntu 14.

Comment: This does not work on Jessie