# Stop systemd service after another at shutdown and reboot

Tags: systemd, shutdown, reboot

I want to run a script at shutdown and reboot after rsyslog has stopped.

What do I have to write in my systemd service file /lib/systemd/system/test.service. So far I have

```
[Unit]
Description=test
RequiresMountsFor=/

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/which/path/should/itbe

[Install]
WantedBy=reboot.target halt.target shutdown.target poweroff.target
```

How can I run this after rsyslog has stopped?

This seems to be the only way [How to run a script at shutdown on Debian 9 or Raspbian 8 (Jessie)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/347275/159562).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an `Before=rsyslog.service` in the `[Unit]` section

By the way, you should probably change the last line with `WantedBy=multi-user.target`

Comment: Do you mean `After=rsyslog.service`? And what's the logic behind `WantedBy=multi-user.target`? It is not so easy to find useful documentation on this.

Comment: Regarding `WantedBy=multi-user.target` it means that it will be added to the dependency chain that leads to the `multi-user.target` (which is the default target started on a machine)

And I was wrong, if you want your service to be stopped After rsyslog you need to set `Before=rsyslog.service` as the order is reversed between the boot and the shutdown.

Comment: Thanks. I also read about the reversed order but nothing official and got confused. But still I am surprised that I have to start a service for another target that what I want to run it for. Anyway I read it at other places too and will do it. But it seem strange.

Comment: Here you are *stopping* the service, not starting it. You could also use `ExecStart=` but the configuration would even be more complex. Regarding the dependencies at shutdown (https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html): "Note that when two units with an ordering dependency between them are shut down, the inverse of the start-up order is applied"

Comment: Ok, thanks. I tested it and it works. Here is the [working example](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/62536/58211).