# Can't get udisksctl to work on system shutdown

Tags: shell-script, debian, systemd, hard-disk, shutdown

I'm trying to gracefully shutdown my HDD's connected to my Rock64 SoC PC (similar to a Raspberry Pi) as the system full shuts down and I've managed to do it with the **udiskstcl** command. I can manually run the file perfectly fine and it does spin down all of the disks, however, upon shutdown it doesn't work.

I have created my shutdown file at

```
/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/graceful_disk_shutdown.shutdown
```

,made it executable and the contents of this file are as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec </dev/null </dev/null 2>/dev/null
export LANG=C LC_ALL=C

# Wait for media to be in idle state.
sync
[ -x /sbin/mdadm ] && /sbin/mdadm --wait-clean --scan

# Function used to power off all SATA disks.
function power_off_disks() {
    for disk in /sys/block/sd* ;
    do
        [ -e $disk ] && /usr/bin/udisksctl power-off -b /dev/${disk##*/}
        sleep 2
    done
}

case "$1" in
    *) 
        power_off_disks
        ;; 
esac
```

Someone else reported it [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=247424) and was told to use **hdparm** instead, which does indeed work for me but it doesn't answer the question to why **udiskctl** doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By the time systemd reads the scripts in /lib/systemd/system-shutdown, the filesystems have already been umounted and are read only.

See this link "https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347275/how-to-run-a-script-at-shutdown-on-debian-9-or-raspbian-8-jessie/347686#347686" as a service using the script placed in say /usr/local/sbin.

Comment: Sadly my HDD is still spinning after the system shuts down.